# UDPClient First Time Using -- What's Wrong?

Tags: c#, udpclient

Wanted to test the UDPClient class out while I was at school.
I am connected to the school's wireless which has a strict firewall.

This code seems pretty solid when compared to this example. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx)
But when I open up wireshark I don't see any of my packets (when I am filtering for UDP packets or otherwise).

Any ideas on what could be wrong with my code? I am thinking it's being blocked by the school's firewall but I'm not sure.

```
  public static void CallBack(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            UdpClient myClient = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
            int sent = myClient.EndSend(result);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent " + sent.ToString() + " bytes");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UdpClient myClient = new UdpClient(57422);
            try
            {
                myClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 57422);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

                int b = 1;
                b = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(b);
                string myName = "ALEX";

                int lengthOfB = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(b).Length;
                int lengthOfName = NUEncoder.GetByteCount(myName);

                Byte[] intBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
                Byte[] nameBytes = NUEncoder.GetBytes(myName);

                Byte[] bytesToSend = new Byte[lengthOfB + lengthOfName];

                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < lengthOfName; i++)
                {
                    bytesToSend[i] = nameBytes[i];
                }

                for (int k = 0; k < lengthOfB; k++)
                {
                    bytesToSend[i] = intBytes[k];
                    i++;
                }

                myClient.BeginSend(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.Length, CallBack, myClient);

                Console.WriteLine("Sleeping...");
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are sending data to your PC (127.0.0.1). I think that this is why you don't see anything with Wireshark.

Comment: No place like 127.0.0.1        ;-)

Comment: I can't send UDP packets to myself?

Comment: It is not that you cannot send, but Wireshark cannot capture such as loopback traffic.